# When to use $\times$ and $\otimes$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, analysis

Im wondering when to use $\times$ and when to use $\otimes$.

In some cases it seems very straightforward, for example $\times$ can be used when combining two elements into an n-tupel (for a product with n elements), for example in the case of the scalar product:
$$(.,.):V\times V\rightarrow\mathbb{C}:(u,v)\mapsto u\cdot v.$$

For the $\otimes$ i've seen it been used when for example one constructs for example the basis  for a $L^2$-Hilbert space where the x,y and z-coordinates can be split up. This yields:

$$f_{nml}(x,y,z)=f_n(x)\otimes f_m(y)\otimes f_l(z).$$

I was wondering if there was a general rule om when to use $\times$ and when to use $\otimes$ ?

Comment: It's the difference between a Cartesian product and a tensor product. Look them up, they are similar in "spirit" but not quite the same!

Comment: @geodude, indeed I've seen that the $\times$ is in some way more strict than than the $\otimes$. But I was wondering if there might be some thumb-rule ?

Comment: A "rule of thumb" can be: $\times$ adds the coordinates, while $\otimes$ multiplies them.
Example: $\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\}\times\{(y_1,y_2)\} = \{(x_1,x_2,x_3,y_1,y_2)\}$, but $\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\}\otimes\{(y_1,y_2)\} = \{(x_1y_1,x_2y_1,x_3y_1,x_1y_2,x_2y_2,x_3y_2)\}$.

Comment: It's a hard choice between the three answers, @SergioSarmiento gives a neat example while user148177 gives a nice discussion on the two. So all three of you well deserved the upvote. Thanks for the answers ! (also copied on the accepted answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The symbol $\times$ has a very strict definition and is almost never used outside it's definition: It is used to calculate the Cartesian product of two sets, meaning $$A\times B = \{(a,b)| a\in A, b\in B\}$$

The symbol $\otimes,$ on the other hand is a more algebraic symbol. It is used to denote the tensor product of two algebraic objects. The general definition (at least the one I know) uses notation from category theory to strictly define what a tensor product of two spaces is.

In the case when the objects are matrix spaces, the $\otimes$ means the [Kronecker product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) of the two matrices, meaning that $$\mathbb R^{m,n}\otimes \mathbb R^{p,q}\subseteq \mathbb R^{mp,qn}.$$ (the cartesian product of the two sets would be $\mathbb R^{mn+pq}$).

Also, another annoying thing about notation is the fact that the elements of $A\otimes B$ are also written as $a\otimes b$ (although, unlike in $A\times B$, not all elements of $A\otimes B$ can be written as $a\otimes b$ for some pair $(a,b)\in A\times B$).

Comment: "The symbol $\times$ has a very strict definition and is almost never used outside it's definition: It is used to calculate the Cartesian product of two sets." Well I agree with the first sentence, but $\times$ is used mathematics-wide to denote categorical products, especially in concrete categories such that forgetful functor to $\mathrm{Set}$ preserves products.

Comment: @5xum, this indeed looks like the kind of answer that I'm looking for. Now from the point of gauge theory, they say the standardmodel is described by $U(1)\times SU(2)\times SU(3)$, but they also use the notation $U(1)\otimes SU(2)\otimes SU(3)$. I'm not sure which one of these is the most correct one ? I was wondering if you might have an idea ?

Comment: @Nick As far as I know, the correct product here is the cartesian one. Cases when $\otimes$ is used are probably typos or sloppy.

Comment: It's a hard choice between the three answers, @SergioSarmiento gives a neat example while user148177 gives a nice discussion on the two. So all three of you well deserved the upvote. Thanks for the answers ! (also copied as comment on the question)

Answer (score 4):

You can find vastly information about the **Cartesian product**, the second one, on the other hand is more sophisticated.

The **tensor product**, also called the *Kronecker product* $(\otimes)$, is defined as follows:

Let

$$X_1 = \begin{bmatrix}a_{1,1} &a_{1,2}\\a_{2,1}&a_{2,2}\end{bmatrix},\ \ X_2 = \begin{bmatrix}b_{1,1} &b_{1,2}\\b_{2,1}&b_{2,2}\end{bmatrix}$$ 
then:
$$\begin{bmatrix}a_{1,1} &a_{1,2}\\a_{2,1}&a_{2,2}\end{bmatrix}\ \otimes \begin{bmatrix}b_{1,1} &b_{1,2}\\b_{2,1}&b_{2,2}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a_{1,1}\begin{bmatrix}b_{1,1} &b_{1,2}\\b_{2,1}&b_{2,2}\end{bmatrix} & a_{1,2}\begin{bmatrix}b_{1,1} &b_{1,2}\\b_{2,1}&b_{2,2}\end{bmatrix}\\ \\ a_{2,1} \begin{bmatrix}b_{1,1} &b_{1,2}\\b_{2,1}&b_{2,2}\end{bmatrix} & a_{2,2}\begin{bmatrix}b_{1,1} &b_{1,2}\\b_{2,1}&b_{2,2}\end{bmatrix} \end{bmatrix}$$

or:
$$X_1 \otimes X_2 =\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1,1}b_{1,1} & a_{1,1}b_{1,2} & a_{1,2}b_{1,1} & a_{1,2}b_{1,2}\\ 
a_{1,1}b_{2,1} & a_{1,1}b_{2,2} & a_{1,2}b_{2,1} & a_{1,2}b_{2,2}\\
a_{2,1}b_{1,1} & a_{2,1}b_{1,2} & a_{2,2}b_{1,1} & a_{2,2}b_{1,2}\\
a_{2,1}b_{2,1} & a_{2,1}b_{2,2} & a_{2,2}b_{2,1} & a_{2,2}b_{2,2}\end{bmatrix} $$

In general if:

$X_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{(m \times n)},\  X_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{(p \times q)}$ then $X_1 \otimes X_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{(mp \times nq)}$

Note that $X_1 \otimes X_2 \neq X_2 \otimes X_1$

Which one you should use depends completely on the task you want to solve.

PS. You have received two other fantastic answers concerning which of the two methods you should apply. Both answers are very thoughtful.

**Edit**

One of many application the *tensor product* has (this one is not so popular as other applications, but is indeed a very important one if one is working with linear-algebra):

Let $X_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{(m \times n)}$ have a singular value decomposition ($U_{X_1} \Sigma_{X_1} V_{X_1}^t$) and let $X_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{(p \times q)}$ have a singular value decomposition ($U_{X_2} \Sigma_{X_2} V_{X_2}^t$). Then:
$$
(U_{X_1} \otimes\ U_{X_2})(\Sigma_{X_1} \otimes\ \Sigma_{X_2})(V_{X_1}^t \otimes\ V_{X_2}^t)
$$
yields a singular value decomposition of $X_1 \otimes X_2$, after a simple reordering of the diagonal elements of $(\Sigma_{X_1} \otimes \Sigma_{X_2})$ and the corresponding right and left singular vectors

Comment: Just a quick addition: The tensor product is defined on much more than just real matrices and is in its core a categorical concept with a fittingly confuzing rigorous definition.

Comment: @Sergio Sarmiento, indeed the kronecker product makes perfect sense to me. The other example (given in the question) is the one that trouwbles me a little bit. I don't know if you are able to elaborate on this one ?

Comment: Just to give a simple example to what @5xum is pointing I have added one of the many applications the tensor product has in my answer! +1 to you 5xum.

Comment: @SergioSarmiento, indeed I notices when I read his comment :D. Do you also know some kind of example on function-spaces ? Like the kind of example used in the question ? (I'm not very sure if that example is more or less correct since physicists just mix $times$ and $\otimes$ up in a very disturbing way).

Comment: Hi @Kick I am complitelly agree that physicists mix times and ⊗ very often. Regarding your question, about the basis which can be split up, I can just think of this basis a combination where all the function values from each vector (form x, y and z) are combined to form this basis. This is what I can tell about your equation from the second part of your very good question. It is not any good answer but I should be cautious because I am not so sure if I have the right answer to your question.

Answer (score 3):

This is by no means a full answer, but you can think of $\otimes$ as an operation on "functions" and $\times$ an operation on "spaces" which are in some sense dual to each other.  Vector spaces are often considered both ways (e.g. a vector bundle is a space, but linear functions on an algebraic variety are not -- this leads to endless confusion at least for me), so it admits both operations.

For instance, $\otimes$ is an operation which must consider some sort of linear structure: a common mistake in proving things about tensor products is to not consider sums.  On the other hand, $\times$ happens on the level of sets.

Also, $\otimes$ and $\times$ do correspond in a way: if $X$ and $Y$ are algebraic varieties, then functions on $X \times Y$ are given by
$$\mathbb{C}[X \times Y] = \mathbb{C}[X] \otimes \mathbb{C}[Y]$$

(Conversely, if $A$ and $B$ are rings, then $Spec(A \otimes B) = Spec(A) \times Spec(B)$)

Edit: Here's an addendum.  Often I find the direct product and direct sum are used interchangably for vector spaces when people really mean the direct sum (even though at least for finite dimensional vector spaces they are teh same, we should think about them differently).

In your example on scalar products, if you want the scalar product map:
$$\langle,\rangle: V ? V \rightarrow V$$
to be a morphism in the category of vector spaces, you MUST use $\otimes$, because we do not have that $\langle x, y \rangle + \langle w, z \rangle = \langle x + w, y + z \rangle$ which should hold if we used a direct sum (or direct product).

However, if you only want to think of it as a map in the category of sets, you can use $\times$ (and in your head you are extending it linearly)